# Display rows in SQL where the difference between columns is 1 day

Tags: sql, date

I have joined 3 tables to provide a date of birth and a date of death.  I now need to filter these results to display when the elapsed time between Birth and Death is 1 day, 2 days etc.

I am struggling to work out how I can do this.  The date format is 2007-12-07 so I can't do a multiple of seconds on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62703776/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Also, date functions are __VERY__ vendor specific. Please tag your question with the actual database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking at with the limited information provided. This is specific to SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @Date TABLE
(
    [DoB] date,
    [DoD] date
)

INSERT INTO @Date
VALUES('2007-12-07','2007-12-08'),('2007-12-07','2007-12-10'),('2008-05-17','2020-07-02'),('2009-10-07','2015-12-25')

SELECT [DoB],
       [DoD],
       DATEDIFF (d, [DoB], [DoD]) AS NumOfDays
  FROM @Date
 ORDER BY NumOfDays
```

Comment: I am using Datediff;

DATEDIFF(day, 'BIRTH_DATE', 'DEATH_DATE') AS DateDiff but getting an Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error

Comment: Check if string is in Date format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15